# How to save BufferedImage to FastDFS in Java?

Tags: java

I have an image and I do somethings with it, finally I get an BufferedImage object(the sub image of original image), now I want to save the sub image to FastDFS without save it in my local, what should I do?

I have already save sub image as file to my local, but I don't want to do like this, because it makes waste.

```
    String oriPicPathInFastDFS = "http://127.0.0.1/xx/xx/xx/xx";
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new URL(oriPicPathInFastDFS));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // do something

    // this is the sub image that I want to save to FastDFS
    BufferedImage subImage = image.getSubimage(5, 5, 5, 5);

    // these code can save the sub image to my local and then upload to fastDFS
    String localPath = "/home/xx/x/xx.jpg";
    File detectionFile = new File(localPath);
    try {
        detectionFile.createNewFile();
        ImageIO.write(subImage, "jpg", detectionFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // upload to fast dfs
```

I want to upload the subImage to fastDFS without save it to my local.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, I got a method to solve this question.

```
    // change the BufferedImage to byte[]
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        boolean flag = ImageIO.write(sunImage, "jpg", out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

    // then save the byteArray to fast DFS
```